# newcommand for $\frac{\mathrm{d}^4q}{\left(2\pi\right)^4}$

Tags: math-mode, macros

Can you give any hints on how to define a new command that writes

```
$\frac{\mathrm{d}^4q}{\left(2\pi\right)^4}$
```

with the options that one can write `$p$` instead of `$q$` (say) and also if one could controll the exponent somehow i.e. the 4?

Comment: sorry the formatting looks horrible...it seems mathematics is forbidden around here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of our site.

Comment: There are two `4`s in your formula -- do you want both controlled or just one of them?

Comment: Sorry I should've let 4 be some variable instead.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go...

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\foo[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#2}#1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{#2}}}
\begin{document}
$\foo{q}{4}$
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- The `[2]` means that `\foo` takes two parameters.
- These parameters are referred to as `#1` and `#2` inside the definition of `\foo`.
- The exponent is written with braces around it -- that is, `blah^{#2}` rather than `blah^#2` -- to handle the case when the exponent is longer than just a single digit.
- The difference between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*` is that the latter defines a command whose parameters must *not* contain paragraph breaks.
- You must only call `\foo` inside math mode.

Comment: Good point regarding bullet three.

Comment: Awesome man, great! This is much needed in QFT.

Comment: Rather than enclosing the denominator term `2\pi` in `\left(` and `\right)`, I'd recommend a simple `(` and `)` pair.

Comment: yes mico but I thought it looked nicer with large () since they're enclosing 2\pi, no?

Comment: I guess you're right Mico...to much left and right might look bad in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Is the following simply what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\horse[3]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1}#2}{\left(2\pi\right)^{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\horse{3}{p}{a} \quad
\horse{4}{q}{b}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

(This is after an updated answer.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Well it was almost what I wanted but I played around and rewrote your code to: 

< \newcommand*\horse[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#2}#1}{\left(2\pi\right)^#2}} >